# jsf composite component convert

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, classcastexception, composite-component, param

I have a composite component

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" />       
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="converter" targets="jsFunction"/>
</cc:interface>

<a4j:jsFunction name="update">
    <a4j:param name="val" assignTo="#{cc.value}" id="jsFunction" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

Which is used as

```
<my:update value="#{bean.value}" >
  <f:converter converterId="beanConverter" for="converter"/>
</my:update>
```

when opening the page I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.richfaces.component.UIParameter cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.ValueHolder
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ConverterTagHandlerDelegateImpl.applyAttachedObject(ConverterTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:120) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletsAttachedObjectHandler.applyAttachedObject(FaceletsAttachedObjectHandler.java:98) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.retargetHandler(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1416) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.retargetAttachedObjects(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:673) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyNextHandler(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:199) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53) [richfaces-a4j-4.5.5.Final.jar:4.5.5.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53) [richfaces-a4j-4.5.5.Final.jar:4.5.5.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53) [richfaces-a4j-4.5.5.Final.jar:4.5.5.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53) [richfaces-a4j-4.5.5.Final.jar:4.5.5.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:206) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53) [richfaces-a4j-4.5.5.Final.jar:4.5.5.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:225) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:994) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:655) [javax.faces-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    ... 63 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: I can explain the problem, but I can't provide the right solution to whatever you're actually trying to achieve as the concrete functional requirement for which you incorrectly thought that this all would be the right solution is unclear. I'd say you're overcomplicating things and you just need an idempotent link.

Comment: I am creating a composite component through which the function a4j: jfFunction must make a set of an id that I want the converter becomes a complex object, but I can not pass the converter as an attribute.

Comment: Yes, that's clear from the code. But it isn't clear which requirement exactly you thought to achieve this way.

Answer (score 1):

The [`<cc:editableValueHolder>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/cc/editableValueHolder.html) should only refer components implementing [`EditableValueHolder` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html). The `<a4j:param>`, as backed by [`org.richfaces.component.UIParameter`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/javadoc/richfaces-components-ui/org/richfaces/component/UIParameter.html), surely isn't such one.

There's also the [`<cc:valueHolder>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/cc/valueHolder.html) which should refer components implementing [`ValueHolder` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/ValueHolder.html), where the `converter` is actually a member of, but still, the `<a4j:param>` [neither](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/javadoc/richfaces-components-ui/org/richfaces/component/UIParameter.html) imlements this interface.

All in all, whatever you're trying to achieve is impossible this way. You need to look for a different approach to solve the problem you tried to solve using this wrong approach. Do note that this problem is not related to composite components. Even outside a composite, you can't apply a converter on `<a4j:param>`.